# How to get a database and collection from MongoDB ClientSession

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to create a connection to a database - collection using a `ClientSession` in pymongo 3.7.1. From the example provided by the doc here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/, it seems possible to get a connection to a database and cursor.

I tried something really similar :

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')  
session = client.start_session()   
session.get_database('test')
```

But the last line raise the following exception :

> AttributeError: 'ClientSession' object has no attribute 'get_database'

I also tried two other more direct access to the database :

```
session['test_database']
session.test_database
```

which raised :

> TypeError: 'ClientSession' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
>   AttributeError: 'ClientSession' object has no attribute 'db_test'

How does the `ClientSession` behaves ? Apparently is does not inherit from the `Client` object, otherwise the previous line would work...

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit I just found, I have to use `session.client` to retrieve the `Client` from the `ClientSession`